# Cargar string en DataGridView

Tags: c#, lista, datagrid

Creo un DataGridView con una columna de CheckBox para poder marcar una u otra fila.

Como origen de datos del DataGridView le paso una lista de strings.
Al pasar el listado, esperaba obtener un datagridview que me mostrase como primera columna, una columna de checkbox y la segunda columna los string de la lista, pero no, en vez de los string me muestra su longitud:

[image: Imagen tabla]

En la columna Length debería (o me gustaría) mostrar los strings pasados a través de la lista y no su longitud.

La manera de generar la columna "Seleccion" es la siguiente:

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
column.HeaderText = "Seleccion";
column.Name = "Seleccion";
column.TrueValue = true;
column.FalseValue = false;
column.IndeterminateValue = false;
column.ThreeState = false;
column.ValueType = typeof(Boolean);

dgRemotas.Columns.Add(column);
```

y para agregar la lista de string hago lo siguiente:

```
dgRemotas.DataSource = list;
```

list está definida como:

```
public List<string> list;
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar los string en vez de su longitud?

Comment: ¿Como llenas la lista `list` y cómo creas la columna `Length`? Si puedes añadir el código mucho mejor!

Comment: La columna length se crea sola al pasarle como datasource el array de string, en vez de crear una columna de strings la crea de longitudes. Lo relleno con un bucle, obteniendo el string de la descripción de los objetos que tengo en un listado

Comment: Y el titulo `Length` de la columna se lo pones en algun lugar o se crea automaticamente?

Comment: lo crea automáticamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por defecto `DataGridView` tiene la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` a true. Teniendo esa propiedad activada, el `DataGridView` trata de obtener las propiedades de los objetos del `DataSource` que le estas pasando. Pero, resulta que `string` solo tiene una propiedad,y esta es `Length`. Por eso te muestra esa columna.

Para solucionarlo, el primer paso es desactivar `AutoGenerateColumns`:

```
dgRemotas.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

Después, debes añadir la segunda columna que debe mostrar los `string` de tu lista:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column2.HeaderText = "Texto";
column2.Name = "Texto";
column2.DataPropertyName = "Valor";
dgRemotas.Columns.Add(column2);
```

Fijate en el `DataPropertyName`. Debemos pasarle en el `DataSource` una lista de objetos que tengan una propiedad que se llame `Valor`, asi que hacemos lo siguiente:

```
dgRemotas.DataSource = lista.Select(x => new { Valor = x }).ToList();
```

De esta manera,generamos una lista de objetos con una propiedad llamada`Valor` que contiene el texto a mostrar.

Answer (score 1):

Por defecto `DataGridView` va a mirar las propiedades de los objetos contenedores de la lista. Para los `string` sólo hay una propiedad - `length`. Entonces, necesitas un contenedor para una cadena, como este:

```
public class StringValue
{
    public StringValue(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    string _value;
}
```

A continuación, enlazas el objeto `List<StringValue>` a la `DataGridView`.

```
List<StringValue> list = new List<StringValue>();

//Rellenamos lista
list.Add(new StringValue("texto"));

dgRemotas.DataSource = list;
```

---

NOTA: Respuesta obtenida de [éste enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-liststring-to-a-datagridview-control).